# Existence of a separating affine functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let be $S$ a separable(non compact)  metric space and $X=C_b(S)$ the set of all bounded continuous functions, then it's topological dual  $X^{\star}=rba(S)$ is the set of all regular Borel additive measures endowed with the variation norm.  Denote by $\mathscr{P}(S)$ the subset of $rba(S)$ of all  additive probability measures, endowed with the weak$^{*}$ topology.

Fix  $\mu$ a extremal point of $ \mathscr{P}(S)$ and  a closed set $\mathcal{F}$ in $\mathscr{P}(S)$ such that the convex hull $co(\mathcal{F})$  do not contains $\mu,$  then it is possible to show that  there is  an affine functional $\ell_{\mu,\mathcal{F}}:\mathscr{P}(S)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that  $\ell_{\mu,\mathcal{F}}(\mu)=0$ and $\ell_{\mu,\mathcal{F}}$ is strictly positive in $\mathcal{F}$

**Question 1:** Is there some way to use the above stated to get a global result, that is, I want to show that there is a affine functional $\ell_{\mu}:\mathscr{P}(S)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\ell_\mu(\mu)=0$ and $\ell_\mu(\nu)>0$ for all $\nu\in \mathscr{P}(S)\setminus \{\mu\}$ ?

**Question 2:** If not, is there some other approach to show that there is a affine functional $\ell_{\mu}:\mathscr{P}(S)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\ell_\mu(\mu)=0$ and $\ell_\mu(\nu)>0$ for all $\nu\in \mathscr{P}(S)\setminus \{\mu\}$ ?

**Edit:** Following the suggestions of Jochen Glueck I had made some edits in the  second paragrapher

Comment: Two remarks: (i) What you claim in the paragraph before Question 1 is not true if $\mu$ is contained in the convex hull of $\mathcal{F}$, so you need an additional assumption such as, e.g., convexity of $\mathcal{F}$, right?

Comment: (ii) Concerning your questions: maybe I'm missing something, but assume that $\mu$ is not an extreme point of $\mathscr{P}(S)$. Then $\mu$ can be written as a convex combination of two points in $\mathscr{P}(S) \setminus \{\mu\}$, so if $\ell_\mu(\nu) > 0$  for all $\nu \in \mathscr{P}(S) \setminus \{\mu\}$, then we always have $\ell_\mu(\mu) > 0$. Doesn't this show that a functional with the properties you are looking for does never exist unless $\mu$ is an extreme point of $\mathscr{P}(S)$?

Comment: And (iii) let's recall that in general a point with that property is called an *exposed point* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposed_point

Comment: As you observe I have to clarify some thinks in the statement, thanks for the warning,  I will rewrite the question.

Comment: Thanks for point out the mistakes  and lack of precision in the statement.

Comment: Eduardo: Thanks for your edit. Concerning (i), I'm not sure whether it suffices if $\mu$ is not contained in the convex hull of $\mathcal{F}$; it is however, certainly sufficient if $\mu$ is not conained in the *closed* convex hull of $\mathcal{F}$. Back to your questions: in your edits, you did not respond to my remark (ii) or to remark (iii) by @PietroMajer.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, but I think your example is  right, $\mu$ need to be  a extreme point, to concern this question. About the PietroMajer observation,  I have not to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a characterization of those $\mu$'s which have the desired property:

**Theorem.** Let $S$ be an arbitrary topoligcal space, let $C_b(S)$ denote the space of bounded real-valued continuous functios on $S$ (endowed with the supremum norm) and let $\mathscr{P}(S)$ denote the subset of the dual space $C_b(S)'$ consisting of those functionals which have norm one and map the positive cone $C_b(S)_+$ into $[0,\infty)$. For each $\mu \in \mathscr{P}(S)$ the followig assertions are equivalent:

(i) $\mu$ is an *extreme point* of $\mathscr{P}(S)$, i.e. $\mu$ cannot be written as a convex combination of two functionals in $\mathscr{P}(S) \setminus \{\mu\}$.

(ii) $\mu$ is an *exposed point* of $\mathscr{P}(S)$, i.e. there exists a functional $g$ in the bi-dual $C_b(S)''$ wich attains its strict miminum on the set $\mathscr{P}(S)$ at the point $\mu$.

(iii) There exists a functional $\tilde g$ in the bi-dual $C_b(S)''$ which is zero at $\mu$ and strictly positive on $\mathscr{P}(S) \setminus \{\mu\}$.

(iv) $\mu$ is a *lattice homomorphism*, i.e. we have $|\langle \mu, f\rangle| = \langle \mu, |f| \rangle$ for all $f \in C_b(S)$.

(v) $\mu$ is an algebra homomorphism, i.e. we have $\langle \mu, f_1f_2 \rangle = \langle \mu, f_1 \rangle \cdot \langle \mu, f_2 \rangle$ for all $f_1,f_2 \in C_b(S)$.

*Proof.* "(i) $\Leftrightarrow$ (iv)" This equivalence is a standard argument in the proof of Kakutani's representation theorem for AM-spaces in the theory of Banach lattices; see for instance [H. H. Schaefer: Banach Lattices and Positive Operators (1974), proof of Theorem II.7.4].

"(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)" Obvious.

"(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii)" Let $g$ be as in (ii), let $1_S \in C_b(S) \subseteq C_b(S)''$ denote the constant function with value $1$ and set $\tilde g = g - \langle g,\mu\rangle 1_S$. Then $\tilde g$ fulfils the properties claimed in (iii) (to see this, note that $\langle 1_S, \nu \rangle = \|\nu\| = 1$ for all $\nu \in \mathscr{P}(S)$).

"(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (i)" Obvious.

"(i) $\Rightarrow$ (iii)" Assume that $\mu$ is an extreme point of $\mathscr{P}(S)$. It follows from Kakutani's representation theorem for AM-spaces [op. cit.] that there exists a Banach lattice isomorphism $\Psi$ between the space $C(K)$ of all real-valued continuous functions on some compact Hausdorff space $K$ and the space $C_b(S)$ and that this isomorphism can be chosen to fulfil $\Psi(1_K) = 1_S$. Now the extreme point property of $\mu$ implies that $\Psi'(\mu) \in C(K)'$ is a delta functional, i.e. there exists a point $\omega \in K$ such that $\Psi'(\mu) = \delta_\omega$, where $\langle \delta_\omega,f\rangle = f(\omega)$ for all $f \in C(K)$; this is again a standard fact in Banach lattice theory (see e.g. [P. Meyer-Nieberg: Banach Lattices (1991), Proposition 2.1.2(i)]). The space of all bounded Borel measurable functions on $K$ is contained in the bi-dual of $C(K)$, so the indicator function $1_{K \setminus \{\omega\}}$ is an element of the bi-dual $C(K)''$ which does not vanish on any positive normalized functional on $C(K)$ except for $\delta_\omega = \Psi'(\mu)$. Consequently, $\tilde g := \Psi'' 1_{K \setminus \{\mu\}} \in C_b(S)''$ does the job in (iii).

"(v) $\Rightarrow$ (iv)" For each $f \in C_b(S)$ we have
\begin{align*}
  |\langle \mu, f\rangle|^2 = \langle \mu,f\rangle^2 = \langle \mu, f^2\rangle =  \langle \mu, |f|^2 \rangle = \langle \mu,|f|\rangle^2,
\end{align*}
which implies (iv).

"(iv) $\Rightarrow$ (v)" This can be shown by an approximation procedure which is, for instance, explained in [T. Eisner, B. Farkas, M. Haase, R. Nagel: Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory (2015), supplement to Chapter~7] (though in a slightly different context).

The proof of the theorem is complete.

**Important remark.** The proof of the implication "(i) $\Rightarrow$ (iii)" above should not trick us into believing that every extreme point $\mu$ of $\mathscr{P}(S)$ is of the form $\mu = \delta_\omega$ for some $\omega \in S$. In fact, the compact space $K$ is usually much larger than $S$ (if, for instance, $S$ is a locally compact space, then the space $K$ is the [Stone–Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) $\beta S$ of $S$).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, extremal points of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ are exactly the deltas (if $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)$ is not a single point $p$, it can easily be written as a mean of two probability measures). In this case, any  nonnegative $f\in C_b(S)$ vanishing exactly at $p $  easily does the job, because then $\int_S fd\nu>0$ for all $\nu\in \mathcal{P}(S)\setminus\{\mu\}.$

Comment: I tend to believe that your right, but I can't find an argument right now that shows that there are no further extremal points. If, for instance, $S = \mathbb{N}$ (i.e. $C_b(S) = \ell^\infty$), then every ultra filter limit defines an *extreme* point of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ (and in fact these are the only extreme points). Your answer says that such an ultra filter is an *extremal* point if and only if the ultra filter is not free. That "feels" right, but I think a rigorous argument (or a reference) would be nice ;-).

Comment: If the deltas are the only  extreme points, then we have no genuinely additive (not $\sigma$-additive) probability measure  as an extreme point?

Comment: Sorry, I see now I misread the definition of $\mathcal{P}(S)$  (as "$\sigma$-additive")

Comment: I thought about it once again, and it seems that my above comment is not correct. Since @Eduardo allows $\ell_\mu$ to be an element of the bi-dual of $C_b(S)$ rather than only an element of $C_b(S)$, it follows that *all* extreme points of $\mathscr{P}(S)$ have the desired property. Moreover, the extreme points of $\mathscr{P}(S)$ are exactly the characters on the $C^*$-algebra $C_b(S)$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Could you elaborate your comment or provide me a reference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Eduardo: Done; see my answer.